# Get server stats by user

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, munin, stats

I run a server with centos, ispconfig, about 100 websites on it. It occasionally gets high load, but I have no real way to pinpoint whats causing this. I really want to see stats of hits/cpu usage per user/website (each site has its own user). This seems like it should be simple, I've tried many reporting packages including Munin, Goaccess etc but none of these give me what I need.

Any suggestions of software which can do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check the location of your Apache log file, In my case i use C-Panel so my location is

```
/usr/local/apache/logs/access_log    --- full server logs
/home/user/access_logs/userdomain.com   --- logs for particular user.
```

Below commands will be useful for identifying cause of high load on Apache.

```
cat access_log| awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c |sort -n
```

**Generates a list of IP address preceded by the number of times it hit a site.**

```
tail -10000 access_log| awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c |sort -n
```

**Generates a list that shows the last 10,000 hits to a site.**

```
awk '{print $7}' access_log|cut -d? -f1|sort|uniq -c|sort -nk1|tail -n10
```

**Generates a list of files or directories on your site being called the most.**

```
for k in `ls -S /home/*/access_logs/*`; do wc -l $k | sort -r -n; done
```

**Generates a list of all traffic for all domains (for multiple domains on a VPS or Dedicated server).**

### Modify as per your log file location...!!!